# Загрузка и проигрывание аудио Android 4+

Tags: java, android, сеть, аудио

Каким способом можно реализовать одновременное проигрывание аудио из интернета и его загрузку на устройство в Android 4+? Подходит ли для этого класс MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужна работа со стриминговыми протоколами, например **WebRTC**, для андроида есть библиотеки для работы с ним. Советую почитать и разобрать этот [туториал](https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial)